# Replacement MOSFET (in a different package)

Tags: mosfet

I'm looking for a replacement MOSFET for the SI7460DP. It's a 60V 11A 0.0096 ohm MOSFET.

I don't think I can solder the PPAK, but a design I am using requires this fet. So I'd be okay with SOT-89, SOT-223, DPAK, SOIC-8 - anything with exposed leads - if it fits the requirements I'd be happy with it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO8 is rare, but DPAK might work. Infineon, for example, has plenty. The IPD088N06N3 (DPAK=TO-252) with 60.0 V and 8.8 mOhm seems to be closest, but there are many more with even smaller Rds,on. To get a good comparison, I suggest relying rather on Rds,on and not on the current rating, because the latter is used differently by various manufactureres.

Comment: Yeah, but what about gate charge? I've heard that's quite important...

Comment: @Thomas - It's only important if you have a weak driver and are very sensitive to the transition times.  Is that the case?

Comment: I don't know. I'm using an LT3757.

Comment: Seems like all 60 V MOSFETs with with about equal on resistance should work in your application. Qg is mentioned in the data sheets, so you could of course go for one that is very similar. What could cause more trouble than Qg is the gate threshold voltage, Vg,th. Make sure that the driver will always put the gate above the MOSFET's Vg,th. Check the IC's UVLO level. It must be higher than the Vg,th to make sure this is also true during start-up.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Renesas HAT2266H - 60V, 9.2 milliohm. It's in a SM package that's a little easier to solder than the Vishay PowerPAK (especially as a rework - trust me, I work with those PowerPAKs and without a hot air tool, forget it)

[Link to datasheet](http://documentation.renesas.com/jpn/products/transistor/rej03g1370_hat2266hds.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

just get some solder paste, apply to the board (not too much), drop on the fet, and bake it... easy